# a simple "paradox"

Tags: geometry, probability-theory

Let $x$ be a random vector uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $b$ be any fixed vector on the unit sphere.

**Goal:** Compute the variance of the random variable $|b^\top x|$.

I have proved that 
$\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(b^\top x) x] = \frac{2}{3} \cdot b$. A little intuition about this
result: $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(b^\top x) x]$ is colinear with $b$, 
because the set $\left\{\operatorname{sign}(b^\top y) y, \, y \in S^2\right\}$ is the hemisphere defined by the direction $b$. The factor $\frac{2}{3}$ is the average height
of the unit hemisphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consequently ,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|b^\top x|]=\mathbb{E}[b^\top \operatorname{sign}(b^\top x) x] = \frac{2}{3}. 
\end{align}

Now, it is known that the covariance matrix of $x$ is $\frac{1}{3} I$, where
$I$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. Then

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[|b^\top x|] &= \mathbb{E}[|b^\top x|^2] - \left(\mathbb{E}[|b^\top x|]\right)^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(b^\top x)^2] - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 \\
&=b^\top \mathbb{E}[x x^\top] b - \frac{4}{9} \\
&= b^\top \left(\frac{1}{3} I\right) b - \frac{4}{9} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} b^\top b - \frac{4}{9} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{4}{9} \\
&= -\frac{1}{9}.
\end{align} But this is impossible because the variance is always non-negative.

**Question:** Where is error?

Comment: I am out of my comfort zone when wading into probability. But you say $\frac23$ as the average height. This 'average' is for what distribution? Is that consistent with the uniform distribution that you use for calculation?

Comment: @PVanchinathan: The underlying distribution is the uniform distribution on the unit sphere. I believe that the error may lie in the $\frac{2}{3}$ factor, even though i can't place it. Let me add an edit on how i did the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average height of the unit hemisphere in $\mathbb R^3$ is $1/2$, not $2/3$. In fact, the height of the points on $S^2$ is [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Volume_and_surface_area).

Comment: I'm averaging in terms of surface area. More precisely, it is $\frac{\int_S hd\sigma}{\int_S d\sigma}=\frac{\int_0^1 h2\pi dh}{\int_0^1 2\pi dh}=\frac{\pi}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your formula does not parse, but I see a couple of problems: 1. The surface area of a unit hemisphere is $2\pi$, not $\pi$. 2. The angle $\phi$ should probably range from $0$ to $\pi$, not $2\pi$. 3. You're averaging on the sphere, so why integrate $r$ from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: I am using a geometric definition, according to which the average height is the integral over the unit disk in $R^2$ of the function $\sqrt{1-r^2}$, divided by the area of the unit disk. That's why i had the $\pi$ in the denominator, $\phi$ was going from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $r$ from $0$ to $1$. Apparently the two notions do not coincide and i am now intrigued to see what's going on.

Comment: I see. That's not the right definition, as you're not averaging over the surface area, but the _projection_ of the surface area onto the equatorial disk. This projection does not preserve the relative proportion of the area elements. To wit, the area element on the top is projected 1:1 down, but the area element just above the equator is compressed by a large factor because they are almost vertical.

Comment: That sounds like an amazing explanation :)